# How can I add site_path define('SITE_PATH','http://127.0.0.1/project/'); in Jquery URL:

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url, url-rewriting

Here my jQuery ajax code

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url:'login.php',
});
```

How can I add site path in (url:'login.php') like we define site path in php define('SITE_PATH','http://127.0.0.1/project/');
I want to use this SITEPATH in url:'login.php'; to display url:'http://127.0.0.1/project/login.php';

Can anyone tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Absolute URL is a good idea in `ajax`. Just declared `var siteURL = www.example.com;` globally. And used this in every `ajax` request like below:-

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: siteURL + '/path/to/file',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
});
</script>
```